# Why does placing multiple bridge rectifiers in parallel reduce the voltage drop?

Tags: parallel, bridge-rectifier

I noticed when you start running these KBP310 bridge rectifiers in parallel the Vf goes down. From 0.998 V for 1 to 0.900 V for X4 bridge rectifiers together. Why would that be? Also, I was thinking if you run 2 bridge rectifiers in parallel but reverse the A/C leads on the second one would that lower ripple and maybe Vf a little because the rectifiers would be out of phase with each other?

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLNkXf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *these IC rectifiers* I don't know what "IC rectifiers" are so include a datasheet. *but reverse the A/C leads* If it is AC then how is reversing the connections going to change anything? Include a schematic as your question is very vague.

Comment: _if you run 2 chips in parallel but reverse the A/C leads on the second one_ That's phyisically impossible. Given that the two diodes are in parallel, you cannot connect one diode one way, and the other diode the other way.

Comment: KBP310. I don't have a schematic. What I'm saying is having the + and - of both chips in parallel but hooking The A/C wires backwards on the second Rectifier like this =x= the = being the chips A/C legs and the x being the A/C source going from the first chip to the second.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in **using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar**. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about full wave bridge rectifiers. Using two with the outputs paralleled and the AC reversed on one will not make a difference in the ripple. Bridge rectifiers are symmetrical, you get the same output no matter which way you connect the AC.,

Answer (score 3):

> *When you start running these KBP310 bridge rectifiers in parallel the Vf goes down. Anyone know why that would be?*

The basic diode (or Shockley) equation explains why: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354866/voltage-across-diode-shockley-equation).

So, if the current through a diode is shared between two diodes then \$I_D\$ drops to half. So then, if you re-arrange the formula to solve for \$V_D\$ you will see that \$V_D\$ drops a little bit for a halving the diode current \$I_D\$. You probably thought that all diodes drop a fixed forward voltage irrespective of forward current? Not true. Reality is more complex.

> *I noticed when you start running these KBP310 bridge rectifiers in
> parallel the Vf goes down. From .998v for 1 to .900v for \$\color{blue}{\boxed{\text{X4}}}\$ bridge
> rectifiers together*

[image]

Image from [here](http://vakits.com/sites/default/files/KBP310%20datasheet.pdf).

> *I was thinking if you run 2 chips in parallel but reverse the A/C
> leads on the second one would that lower ripple and maybe Vf a little
> because the rectifiers would be out of phase with each other?*

No, it won't make the slightest difference.

Comment: @allenw do you know what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Your data and a linear model of saturated diode with bulk resistance tells you why.

> .998v for 1 to .900v for X4

This means 4 Rs  drops 98 mV @ 1A shared by 4 equal diodes (assumption)  so 4Rs=98 mV/0.25A thus Rs of each diode is 100 mohms @ 0.25A and 1 diode will drop 0.1V @ 1A